# Help constructing a variable satisfying given conditions.

Tags: real-analysis

I have $x,y >0\in \mathbb{R}$, and every integer $n>0$.

Assuming $y^n<x  $, choose an $h$ such that $0<h<1$.

Now the book creates this for me, my problem is that I dont see how I could verify that this would hold:

$$h<\frac{x-y^n}{n (y+1)^{n-1}}$$

How would we be able to verify that this hold?

I sett that the numerator would be positive, so I need to verify that the denominator would max, be equal to the numerator. But I am not sure how?

Comment: Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin theorem 1.21 has the answer.

Comment: Can you please clarify: is $n$ a given, or something we are supposed to pick to make the statement true? or is it supposed to be true for all $n$? (Or at least for all $n$ for which $y^n < x$, as that statement could only be true for all $n$ if $y \le 1$.)